# How to accept argument after ${@:3} shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have specified variables in the shell script as follows

```
USERNAME="$1"
PASSWORD="$2"
DATA="${@:3}"
DATAVERSION="$4"
```

when I run the script is goes something like this:

```
./abc.sh "name" "password" csv V1
```

But when here csv and V1 are considered as 3rd argument instead of considering V1 as the fourth argument Because of ${@:3} which I needed.

So how one can end this ${@:3} while passing the argument to script. So that arguments can be read?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. `${@:3}` means the rest of the arguments; how could `$4` not be a part of that list? In the trivial case, reorder the arguments and use `$3` for `DATAVERSION` and `${@:4}` for `DATA`. (Also, tangentially, [don't use upper case for your private variables.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: `string=${@}` is itself buggy, whether you take an argument subset or not. You can't safely stuff an _array_ into a _string_: when you do so there's no way to tell if you started with `set -- "two words" "two more"` or `set -- two words two more`. It needs to be `data=( "${@:3}" )`, making `data` a _list_ not a _string_, to avoid destroying information (after doing that you can separately return to `"${data[0]}"` vs `"${data[1]}"`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) command line:

One of most powerfull feature of bash is: You could try inline near every part of your script.

For making tries around *arguments parsing*: simply open any *terminal* window and try :

```
set -- "Full Name" "password" csv V1
```

From there, you're in (near) same condition than a script that was run with this arguments: `myscript "Full Name" "password" csv V1`. So you could:

```
echo $1
Full Name

echo ${@:3}
csv V1

echo ${@:0:3}
/bin/bash Full Name password

echo ${@:1:3}
Full Name password csv
```

so

```
userName=$1
passWord=$2
datas=${*:3}
dataVersion=$4

printf '%-12s <%s>\n' userName "$userName" passWord "$passWord" \
                  datas "$datas" dataVersion "$dataVersion"
```

Must produce:

```
userName     <Full Name>
passWord     <password>
datas        <csv V1>
dataVersion  <V1>
```

#### Using `shift`

Or ...

```
set -- "Full Name" "password" csv V1
```

Then

```
userName=$1
shift
passWord=$1
shift
datas=$*
shift
dataVersion=$1

printf '%-12s <%s>\n' userName "$userName" passWord "$passWord" \
                      datas "$datas" dataVersion "$dataVersion"
```

will produce:

```
userName     <Full Name>
passWord     <password>
datas        <csv V1>
dataVersion  <V1>
```

Regarding [tripleee's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69879281/how-to-accept-argument-after-3-shell-script/69879630#comment123523924_69879281) about capitalized variable names, my preference is to use [lowerCamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

Comment: Some people call that dromedaryCase (camels have two humps, dromedaries just one).

Comment: @tripleee Yes, *dromedaryCase* or *lowerCamelCase* (with two humps). Anyway important thing is: it's not ALLCAPS! (And remain more readable)

Comment: No, no, only bactrian camels have two humps. So in that sense, since dromedary camels have only one -- camelCase can be ambiguous. But still when compared between "camelCase" and "TitleCase", etc.. the meaning is fairly obvious. Simply using lowercase avoids the whole camel discussion `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In french, there is no ambiguity: Camel is *chameau* and have **two** humps. More informations about: [kINd oF caPiTaLiSAtIOn](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/533036/62976)

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep a note of that to use a proper naming convention

Comment: I've been schooled... I would have never thought folks put so much time into defining case. The "Studly case" was a completely new use of the "Studly" and in my mid 50s with 25 years practicing law -- I thought I had seen it all -- nope...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So U won't be surprised that bash's man page was recently patched to avoid gendered expression. https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-06/msg00016.html

Comment: ......... touché