# Create a new directory in Bash Scripting from argument

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a simple program to create a new folder
from an argument passed by the user. From this I get the error
*mkdir: cannot create directory "": No such file or directory* when I'm passing an argument.

```
echo $folder 

if [ ! -d "$folder" ];
    then
    mkdir -p "$folder"
fi
```

Comment: In your script you can access the first argument passed to it (from the command line) with `$1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69879281/how-to-accept-argument-after-3-shell-script/69879630#69879630